# IndexOutOfBoundsException in RecyclerView with custom layouts

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

in my RecyclerView i have 3 different custom layouts one is header view for top story and has to be inflated at position 0. the second view is for normal stories which has to be inflated from position 1 onwords. the third one is special layout for breaking story and also should be inflated in position other than 0.

i managed to do that in `onBindViewHolder()` method of recyclerView:

```
   public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof ViewHolderHeaderMain) {
            ViewHolderHeaderMain viewHolderHeaderMain = (ViewHolderHeaderMain) holder;
            viewHolderHeaderMain.getMainHeaderView().setTopStories(this.mTopStory);
        } else if (holder instanceof ViewHolderBaisc){
            ViewHolderBaisc viewHolderItem = (ViewHolderBaisc) holder;
            viewHolderItem.bindStory(this.mStories.get(position -1));
        } else if (holder instanceof ViewHolderNew){
            ViewHolderNew viewHolderNew = (ViewHolderNew) holder;
            viewHolderNew.bindStory(this.mStories.get(position));
        }
}
```

then the view type is returned like:

```
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position != 0) {
            if (mStories.get(position).getIsBreaking() ){
                return ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_CUSTOM;
            }
            return mStories.get(position) != null ? ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_BASIC : ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

my problem is that, the last item of `ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_BASIC` view is not shown

following is my getItemCount method

```
 public int getItemCount() {
        return (this.mStories != null) ? this.mStories.size() : 0;
    }
```

here if i make `return (this.mStories != null) ? this.mStories.size()+1: 0;`
i get

> IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 10, size is 10

Comment: missing the part where you define which holder goes with which item type.

Comment: but probably `viewHolderNew.bindStory(this.mStories.get(position));` should be `position - 1`

Answer (score 0):

In your getItemViewType, you have

```
return mStories.get(position)
```

and in the get count you are doing

```
return (this.mStories != null) ? this.mStories.size() : 0;
```

So you want to return this.mStories.size()+1 and then in your getItemViewType you want to make sure position is less than the size of your array. if position is >= size then you return FOOTER etc. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The line where you access the item:

```
mStories.get(position)
```

Will throw this exception you pass in an invalid position. Instead, you should be checking if the position is less than the size of that list. Try adding in this:

```
if(position < mStories.size() && mStories.get(position) != null) {
   return ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_BASIC;
} else {
   return ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that solved my problem is to make `mStories.get(position -1)` in `getItemViewType`

```
if (position != 0) {
  if (mStories.get(position -1).getIsBreaking() ){
     return ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_CUSTOM;
   }
 return mStories.get(position -1) != null ? ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_BASIC : ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER;
            }
            return 0;
```

now, all items are shown and position has been fixed.

appreciation goes to the hints given here